# Как задать интервал между числовыми значениями? d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

Допустим имеется `SVG` контейнер размером `800x600px`.
Я пытаюсь сделать интервал между значениями в 40px, то есть по оси `X` через каждые 40px должны располагаться числа (от 0 до 20), а по оси `Y` тоже через каждые 40px должны располагаться числа (от 0 до 15).
Как это сделать? Я использую `d3.js v5`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function isInteger(num) {
  return (num ^ 0) === num;
}

var width = window.innerWidth ||
  document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight ||
  document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
  document.body.clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select(".board").append("svg")
  .attr("id", "board")
  .attr("width", width - 20)
  .attr("height", height - 20)
// .append("g");

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  // .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, width]);
y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]).range([0, height]);

var x_axis = d3.axisTop(x_scale)
  .ticks( ? ) //I dont know what do I have to write
  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    if (isInteger(d)) {
      return d;
    }
  })
  .tickSize(5)
var x_axis_group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
  .call(x_axis);

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft(y_scale)
  .ticks( ? ) / I dont know what do I have to write
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      if (isInteger(d)) {
        return d;
      }
    })
    .tickSize(5);
  var y_axis_group = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 20)")
    .call(y_axis);

function zoomed() {
  var new_x_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_scale);
  var new_y_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y_scale);

  x_axis_group.call(x_axis.scale(new_x_scale));
  y_axis_group.call(y_axis.scale(new_y_scale));
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.box,
.reset,
.x,
.y,
.board {
  display: block;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  z-index: 100;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.y {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.board {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#board {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

g.tick line {
  stroke: #D3D3D3;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

g.tick text {
  fill: #C4C4C4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="reset"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="y"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: исправьте ошибки в примере, иначе мало желающих будет вам помочь

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте ошибки в примере (их несколько, отсутствие ; и т.п.), иначе мало желающих будет вам помочь.

Есть не до конца сформулированный вопрос и неработающий пример, я исправил пример что бы он хоть что то выводил на экран, похожее на то что нужно автору.

```js
function isInteger(num) {
  return (num ^ 0) === num;
}

var width = window.innerWidth ||
  document.documentElement.clientWidth ||
  document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight ||
  document.documentElement.clientHeight ||
  document.body.clientHeight;

var svg = d3.select("#board").append("svg")
  .attr("id", "board")
  .attr("width", width - 20)
  .attr("height", height - 20);
// .append("g");

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  // .scaleExtent([1, 32])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

svg.call(zoom);

x_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 21]).range([0, width]);
y_scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 16]).range([0, height]);

var x_axis = d3.axisTop(x_scale)
  .ticks( 21 ) //I dont know what do I have to write
/*  .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    if (isInteger(d)) {
      return d;
    }
  })*/
  .tickSize(5);
var x_axis_group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(20, 0)")
  .call(x_axis);

var y_axis = d3.axisLeft(y_scale)
  .ticks( 16 ) // I dont know what do I have to write
/*    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
      if (isInteger(d)) {
        return d;
      }
    })*/
    .tickSize(5);
  var y_axis_group = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)")
    .call(y_axis);

d3.select("div.x").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width-20)
    .attr("height", 20)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,20)")
    .call(x_axis);

d3.select("div.y").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", height-20)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
    .call(y_axis);




function zoomed() {
  var new_x_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x_scale);
  var new_y_scale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(y_scale);

  x_axis_group.call(x_axis.scale(new_x_scale));
  y_axis_group.call(y_axis.scale(new_y_scale));
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.box,
.reset,
.x,
.y,
.board {
  display: block;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.reset {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  z-index: 100;
}

.x {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.y {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
}

.board {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#board {
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
}

path.domain {
  stroke: none;
}

g.tick line {
  stroke: #D3D3D3;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

g.tick text {
  fill: #C4C4C4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="reset"></div>
  <div class="x"></div>
  <div class="y"></div>
  <div class="board"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы

Comment: есть не до конца сформулированный вопрос и неработающий пример, я исправил пример что бы он хоть что то выводил на экран, похожее на то что нужно автору. Не понимаю что тут можно было написать в ответе.

Comment: хотя бы то, что вы написали в комментарии. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]